# How to bind an advBandedGridView at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, master-detail, xtragrid

I am new in the using of DevExpress. I need to design and bind a complex DataGrid.

I have designed it using the Designer. The datagrid is of type Master-Detail, and it contains the 'MainGrid' and other detail grids. One of them is of type: 'advBandedGridView'

The design of the MainGrid is as shown below:

[image]

And the design of the 'advBandedGridView' is as follows:

[image]

Now, I need to fill my DataGrid using Lists collections, so I used the following Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
            Term_Space_Grid t = new Term_Space_Grid("x", "y", true, "z");
            t.expansions = new List<MyExpansions>();
            t.expansions.Add(new MyExpansions(0, "Aya", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
            a.Add(t);
            resultsGridControl.DataSource = a;


        }
    }

    public class Term_Space_Grid
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string g { get; set; }
        public bool z { get; set; }
        public List<MyExpansions> expansions { get; set; }

        public Term_Space_Grid(string x, string y, bool z, string g)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
            this.g = g;

        }
    }
    public class MyExpansions
    {
        public Morphos morphos { get; set; }
        public Semantics semantics { get; set; }  

        public MyExpansions(int morphoID, string morphoDerivation, int synID, int subID, int supID, int hasID, int insID)
        {
            this.morphos = new Morphos(morphoID, morphoDerivation);
            this.semantics = new Semantics(synID, subID, supID, hasID, insID);

        }

    }

    public class Morphos
    {
         //public List<Morph> morph{ get; set; }
        public Morph morph { get; set; }

         public Morphos(int morphoID, string morphoDerivation)
        {

            //this.morph = new List<Morph>();
            //this.morph.Add(new Morph(morphoID, morphoDerivation));
            this.morph = new Morph(morphoID, morphoDerivation);
         }
    }      

    public class Semantics
    {
        public List<Sem> synonyms { get; set; }
        public List<Sem> subClasses { get; set; }
        public List<Sem> superClasses { get; set; }
        public List<Sem> hasInstances { get; set; }
        public List<Sem> instanceOf { get; set; }

        public Semantics(int id1,int id2, int id3, int id4, int id5 )
        {
            this.synonyms = new List<Sem>();
            this.subClasses = new List<Sem>();
            this.superClasses = new List<Sem>();
            this.hasInstances = new List<Sem>();
            this.instanceOf = new List<Sem>();

            this.synonyms.Add(new Sem(id1));
            this.subClasses.Add(new Sem(id2));
            this.superClasses.Add(new Sem(id3));
            this.hasInstances.Add(new Sem(id4));
            this.instanceOf.Add(new Sem(id5));
        }
    }

     public class Morph
    {
         public int MorphoID { get; set; }
        public string MorphoDerivation { get; set; }

         public Morph(int morphoID, string morphoDerivation)
        {
            this.MorphoID = morphoID;
            this.MorphoDerivation = morphoDerivation;
         }
    }
    public class Sem
    {
        public int SemID { get; set; }
        //public string MorphoDerivation { get; set; }

        public Sem(int semID)
        {
            this.SemID = semID;

        }
    }
}
```

However, I found that the result is built as a new DataGrid that has not any designed form. I mean that the detail tabs that I define in the Designer are not appeared in the resulted grid.

The result is as follows:

[image]

Notes

1. The design of the resulted grid which is totally different from my design, I think it is just like the Lists objects.
2. The other problem which is the appearance of :
   "WindowsFormsApplication2.Morphos" and "WindowsFormsApplication2.Semantics" at the cells of the grid rather than the values that I passed!

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, you should create associations between your data object properties and GridView columns via [GridColumn.FildName](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_FieldNametopic) property.
For your main view (`gridView2`) it looks like this:

```
// gridColumn1
this.gridColumn1.Caption = "ID";
this.gridColumn1.FieldName = "x"; // associate this column with Term_Space_Grid.x property
this.gridColumn1.Name = "gridColumn1";
```

Please read the following article for more details: [Creating Columns and Binding Them to Data Fields](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument639)

**Secondly**, you can not directly bind columns to object's nested properties (for example  to `MyExpansions.semantics.subclasses.SemID`).

To bypass this restriction you can use several approaches:

1. The simplest approach is using [Unbound Columns](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) and the corresponding [ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event (you can handle this event to provide data from nested objects).
2. You can also use the approach demonstrated in the following KB article: [How to display and edit complex data properties in grid columns](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A579.aspx?searchtext=ITypedList&p=T4%7CP0%7C56)

**Thirdly**, to get official and guaranteed answer you should address any urgent question related to any DevExpress products directly to [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center).